# Dynamically tagging of AWS resources

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm new to this and I'd like to get some ideas in terms of a code that can dynamically tag AWS resources. I'm confuse as to what will trigger the execution of the code that will tag it. Can someone please point me to right resources and sample codes?

Comment: What would you like it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to monitor CloudTrail events for creation of resources you would like to tag and invoke a Lambda function for the matching events, which tags
the resources accordingly.

1. CloudWatch Event Rule is setup to monitor :create* API calls via CloudTrail.
2. This rule triggers the lambda function whenever a matching event found.
3. The Lambda function fetches the resource identifier and principal information from the event and tags the resources accordingly.

I've devised a [solution](https://github.com/erhanux/aws-solutions-cdk/tree/master/auto_tags) to tag EC2 resources for governance. It is developed in CDK Python and uses Boto3 to attach tags. 
You can further extend this code to cover other resource types or maintain a DynamoDb table to store additional tags per principal 
such as Project, Team, Cost Center. You can then simply fetch the tags of a principal and apply them all at once.

Comment: If I create an EC2 instance, an S3 bucket or any resource, will CloudTrail see that or do I have to setup something in CloudTrail for it to see it?

Comment: Yes it records every API call by default. The only exception is S3 data events (e.g. s3:PutObject), which can be configured at the bucket-level. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/logging-data-events-with-cloudtrail.html#logging-data-events

Comment: I'd like to run cdk deploy. Is it safe? Is it going to overwrite anything? I got this when I execute cdk deploy - "This deployment will make potentially sensitive changes according to your current security approval level (--require-approval broadening). Please confirm you intend to make the following modifications:" I ran it inside the auto_tags directory. I followed all your steps in auto_tags/README.md

Comment: Cdk shows the changeset. It just deploys a Lambda and creates a CWE and required policies.

Comment: The lambda func got created after running cdk deploy so I created a new ec2 instance. I am not sure if it's working or not. Should I expect to see the tags defined in auto_tags/app.py? If so, it doesn't match what I'm seeing. Here's a screenshot - https://i.imgur.com/oGcY4re.png

Answer (score 0):

You can write lambda functions and use Cloudwatch events to trigger that function which will assign tag to your resources.
You can use AWS [nodejs-sdk](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/) or [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html) for Python.

Comment: Great! I'll check those 2 links you sent! I'm assuming those 2 modules you linked are for lambda function, correct?

Comment: @devwannabe yes !!